# Understanding MVVM on Android - lost data after fragment refresh

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mvvm, dagger-hilt

I am trying to understand MVVM architecture and I need a bit of a help.
My goal is to prevent lost data when current fragment has some changes.

I have created simple app with product grid as RecyclerView divided by 3 columns. In my **HomeFragment.class** I have done this:

```
@Inject
RecyclerViewProductAdapter recyclerViewProductAdapter;

@Inject
HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

private final RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager =
        new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), GRID_SPAN_COUNT);

private FragmentHomeBinding binding;


public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View root = binding.getRoot();

    homeViewModel.getProductList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), userListUpdateObserver);

    return root;
}

Observer<ArrayList<Product>> userListUpdateObserver = products -> {
    recyclerViewProductAdapter.setProducts(products);
    binding.productRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    binding.productRecyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewProductAdapter);
};
```

I also created HomeViewModel as @Singleton with injected mock data:

```
@Singleton
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

@Inject
ArrayList<Product> products;

private MutableLiveData<ArrayList<Product>> productList;

public HomeViewModel(Context context) {
    HomeViewModelAccessor homeViewModelAccessor =
            EntryPoints.get(context, HomeViewModelAccessor.class);
    this.products = homeViewModelAccessor.getProducts();
}

public LiveData<ArrayList<Product>> getProductList() {
    if (productList == null) {
        productList = new MutableLiveData<>(products);
    }
    return productList;
}

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public interface HomeViewModelAccessor {
    ArrayList<Product> getProducts();
}

}
```

And the last one, RecyclerViewAdapter that defines every single item what look like. Standard behaviour should mark as "checked" clicked product. After changing fragment to another one and resuming **HomeFragment**, it should save state with proper checkbox checked or not:

```
@Singleton
public class RecyclerViewProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewProductAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private final Context context;
private final DecimalFormat decimalFormat;
private final LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private ArrayList<Product> products;

public RecyclerViewProductAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    ProductAdapterAccessor productAdapterAccessor =
            EntryPoints.get(context, ProductAdapterAccessor.class);
    this.decimalFormat = productAdapterAccessor.decimalFormat();
}

public void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.product_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.lifecycle.setCurrentState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED);
    Product product = products.get(position);
    holder.bind(position, product);
}

@Override
public void onViewRecycled(@NonNull ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.lifecycle.setCurrentState(Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED);
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements LifecycleOwner {
    LifecycleRegistry lifecycle = new LifecycleRegistry(this);

    TextView productNameTextView;
    TextView productPriceTextView;
    ImageView productImageView;
    CheckBox productChecked;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        productNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        productPriceTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        productImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
        productChecked = itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_checked);
    }

    void bind(int position, Product product) {
        productNameTextView.setText(product.getName());
        productPriceTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(product.getPrice()));

        Drawable image = Optional.ofNullable(product.getImage())
                .map(imageBinary -> new BitmapDrawable(
                        context.getResources(),
                        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBinary, 0, imageBinary.length)))
                .orElse(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources()));
        productImageView.setImageDrawable(image);
        productChecked.setChecked(product.isChecked());

        itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            boolean currentState = !product.isChecked();
            product.setChecked(currentState);
            productChecked.setChecked(currentState);
            products.set(position, product);
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Lifecycle getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycle;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return products.size();
}

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public interface ProductAdapterAccessor {
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat();
}
}
```

But my state is lost, even HomeViewModel and RecyclerViewAdapter are singletons. I wonder why observer of product list do not save fragment state?

I should create my fragments as singletons? How can I handle this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi there looking at your code above i can notice that you dont have a complete understanding of MVVM, but not to worry your 75% there, i would suggest you to watch this youtube tutorial , its worth it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ct5etYgB5pQ&t=1775s&ab_channel=PhilippLackner in this he uses dagger hilt as well.

Comment: I would check out the official Hilt tutorial, it outlines how to manage view models properly and what dependency injection is. You shouldn't be injecting your adapter, your data etc.

Comment: @HenryTwist All right, so adapter should be created once in my fragment? I'll check out official page.

Comment: Yes, unless you have good reason to inject it, it seems unnecessary.